# In Ubuntu, how to reduce the non-responsive pop-ups

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

Using Ubuntu from a USB stick, I get a lots of pop ups, mostly with Chrome, which say that the application is non-responsive. I just need to wait a little (click wait) and all is good; Chrome is indeed not crashed.

The stick is USB-C so at that level the performance is likely Ok; but in the end,the stick is a single NAND flash chip and that bottleneck is unavoidable.

The machine has sufficient system memory (8GB) so I do not think that is where the problem is.

Is it possible to make the non-responsive detection mechanism less sensitive? Any other tweaks that would be useful?

Answer (score 1):

GNOME Shell makes the timeout configurable through GSettings as `check-alive-timeout` within the `org.gnome.mutter` settings schema. The default is 5000 (i.e. 5 seconds).

Use `dconf-editor org.gnome.mutter` or `gsettings set ...` to change the setting.

Comment: Good answer -- but note, to make the setting change "stick" beyond the current session, the USB media would need *persistence* to store data. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1330368/live-usb-with-persistence-vs-full-install-on-usb . BTW, on a slow flash USB drive, persistent Ubuntu is *slow*. Use the fastest media available, but expect writing to be lethargic.

Answer (score 0):

Not much that you can do :

- Ensure that the port and disk are USB3
- Get a faster USB stick.